# Will google appengine legacy services based python2 standard runtime application continue to work after appcfg tool shutdown?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, appcfg

One of our projects uses Memcache, Mail API, Task Queue, Cloud KMS V1, and other legacy app engine services for Python 2 (standard env). If we can build this project with gcloud, will this continue to work after August 30 (after appcfg build tool shutdown)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to build your application with `gcloud` commands, the services you will be using, such as Memcache, Mail API, Task Queue, etc., as informed in this official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrating-services), should still work, however, bear in mind that they won't be supported, as Python 2 is not supported anymore.

It's recommended for you to migrate your application to Python 3, so you have access to the new features and support for those same features as well.